# Load info on click from another page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a page where I click a button and it loads elements from another page with js. I however have a separate page where I want to click a link and go directly to the page but with a button result up. What goes into that? Is there a better method than just using `$_GET` and sending it over right away?

Right now I have:

index.php

```
<div class="Tab-Button" id="A" onclick="showList('A')"><p>A</p>
```

Script

```
function showList(str) {
    $.get( "GetTable.php?q="+str, function( data ) {
      $( "#TableSpot" ).html( data );
});
}
```

Seperate Page

```
<a href="alink.com/index.php?q=A">A</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use $_GET, i think the other way to go is $_POST, meaning your buttons will be represented as an element of a form... A form for each button if they are far apart, or a single form for everything if they are together... something like this

```
<form action="alink.com/index.php" method="post">
    <button name="showList" value="A">A</button>
</form>
```

then in your receiving file, you check for `$_POST['showList']`, get your value and use it accordingly.. Hope this helps